# How to I execute multiple functions on the result of a ternary operation?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have an if/else statement that results in two functions being called if it evaluates as true.

```
if (isTrue) {
    functionOne();
    functionTwo();
} 
else {
    functionThree();
}
```

I would like to be able to put that in a ternary statement like this:

```
isTrue ? (functionOne(), functionTwo()) : functionThree();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can do it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) but why?

Comment: A ternary operator returns a value.  You seem to be using as a one-liner "if" statement, that returns no value.  That's not the intended use.

Comment: just wrap your statements in parentheses*()* and separate them with a comma*,*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your example is indeed valid javascript. [You can use a comma to separate expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and wrap that in a single statement with parentheses for the ternary.

```
var functionOne   = function() { console.log(1); }
var functionTwo   = function() { console.log(2); }
var functionThree = function() { console.log(3); }
var isTrue = true;

isTrue ? (functionOne(), functionTwo()) : functionThree();
// 1
// 2

isTrue = false;
isTrue ? (functionOne(), functionTwo()) : functionThree();
// 3
```

However, this is not advisable. Your version with an `if` statement is far more clear and readable, and will execute just as fast. In most codebases I've ever seen or worked with, the comma operator is *never* used this way as it's far more confusing than it is helpful.

Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Be advised, this should be used with caution (or not used at all) when those functions are supposed to actually return something (say you use two functions and you want both of them to render something in ReactJS) as the comma operator **only returns the right-hand side function's value**.

Answer (score 6):

You can always wrap anything into an anonymous function and call it immediately, the so called [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), like so

```
isTrue ? (function() { functionOne(); functionTwo() })() : functionThree();
```

But as you can see it looks pretty darn terrible and is a pretty bad misuse of the ternary operator (it doesn't return anything useful) so I'd really recommend against doing that.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason what worked for me was returning both functions as objects in an array. Otherwise the ternary operator only returned the last function. See below example:

```
isTrue ? [fucnctionOne(), functionTwo()] : functionThree()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just wrap your statements in **parentheses***()* and separate them with a **comma***,*

```
condition ? (doThis, andThis) : (doThat, andThat)
```

In your case (OP):

```
isTrue ? (functionOne(), functionTwo()) : functionThree();
```