# How to have two function calls inside ternary operator in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

I am trying to render two components if the condition is met inside a ternary operator. However, only the 2nd component is rendered. How can I probably put two functions calls after the conditions?

```
    {
      views === "monthly"
      ? this.renderDays(),
        this.renderCells()
      : null
    }
```

I tried the followings (none of them works)

```
    {
      views === "monthly"
      ? this.renderDays(),
        this.renderCells()
      : null
    }

    {
      views === "monthly"
      ? (this.renderDays(), this.renderCells())
      : null
    }

    {
      views === "monthly"
      ? (this.renderDays(); this.renderCells())
      : null
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I execute multiple functions on the result of a ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950027/how-to-i-execute-multiple-functions-on-the-result-of-a-ternary-operation)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could return an array of components:

```
{
  views === "monthly"
  ? [this.renderDays(), this.renderCells()]
  : null
}
```

Or if the methods return arrays itself, just spread them:

```
 {
  views === "monthly"
  ? [...this.renderDays(), ...this.renderCells()]
  : null
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, @jonas-w. But how do we solve the unique key props issue when returning an array of components like that?

Comment: Based on the possible duplicate linked in the comment of the original post, it seems that for the comma operator both functions execute, but you only get the return value of the right hand function. So you couldn't render the results of both functions, only the right hand one. Whereas this array approach will render both, as all array elements get rendered.

Comment: @geekydude the components should have keys based on their content, otherwise react will assign increasing keys to them

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comma to separate expressions and wrap that in a single statement with parentheses for the ternary.

```
{  views === "monthly"  ? (this.renderDays(), this.renderCells()): null   }
```

Reference: [How to I execute multiple functions on the result of a ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950027/how-to-i-execute-multiple-functions-on-the-result-of-a-ternary-operation)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the functions inside parenthesis because if you use comma seperated function call like - `this.renderDays(),this.renderCells()` then it will throw you a syntax error as ternary condition allow `?` and `:`. So, use parenthesis to wrap the multiple function call:

```js
function renderDays(){
  console.log('renderDays')
}
function renderCells(){
  console.log('renderCells')
}
1 == 1? (renderDays(), renderCells()): console.log('False');
```

Comment: Thanks @ankit. I tried this, but for some reasons, it doesn't work on my case and it only rendered the 2nd function call.

Comment: @geekydude703 then wrap them in a new function and call that function in the ternary condition

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine both the function in the parathesis and then separate them with the help of comma and then easily able to call both.

They will be treated internally as the function call only.