# Ternary statement with multiple results

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a function in which I pass an `query` argument which is a string. If the query is not empty the function calls the `toggleList` with the true boolean and otherwise with the false.

I also have a `setMovies` function that accepts an array. I want to do this function if query is not empty.

```
query ? toggleList(true) : toggleList(false);

if (query) { 
  setMovies([...movies]);
}
```

But I can't do something like this:

```
query ? (toggleList(true), setMovies([...movies])) : toggleList(false);
```

Is it not possible to call 2 functions in the truth part of the ternary statement because this way I'm implementing too much logic and I should just use a normal if/else statement, or is there something I'm missing that does makes this possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I execute multiple functions on the result of a ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950027/how-to-i-execute-multiple-functions-on-the-result-of-a-ternary-operation)

Comment: since input of toggleList is based solely on the value of query you could try to simplify it to `toggleList(Boolean(query))` and trigger it regardless of query value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a clean approach.

```
toggleList(!!query);               // if query is already boolean take it without !!
if (query) setMovies([...movies]);
```

Comment: What do you think about this `query ? (() => { toggleList(true); setMovies([...movies]) })() : toggleList(false);` ? This seems pretty straightforward if you know ternary statements right?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma, the ternary returns an expresion which is not used with your code. it is not easy to follow and is directly called (iife), which is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If first function called has a falsey return value ex undefined you could just use || operator to trigger both of them

```
query ? toggleList(true) || setMovies([...movies]) : toggleList(false);
```

If it's truthy you would accordingly use &&

```
query ? toggleList(true) && setMovies([...movies]) : toggleList(false);
```

Example:

```js
function f1(){
  console.log("f1");
}

function f2(){
  console.log("f2");
}

function f3(){
  console.log("f3");
}

true ? f1() || f2() : f3(); // logs both f1 and f2
false ? f1() || f2() : f3(); // logs f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary Operators are used for easy one line if/else cases.
If you want to implement more complex logic like in your case use the standard if/else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous function call

```js
const func1 = a => console.log('1', a)
const func2 = b => console.log('2', b)

true
  ? (() => {
      func1('a')
      func2('b')
    })()
  : func2('c')
```

or

```js
const func1 = a => console.log('1', a)
const func2 = b => console.log('2', b)

true ? (func1(1), func2(2)) : func2(2)
```

Comment: The bottom example gives: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` That was also my example. Your first example does indeed work but much less readable than a norma if/else statement, but thanks for showing it can be done.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma talking about the bottom example, I wonder what js environment you used? I ran bottom with node, and in browser console and still cannot see any error

Comment: running it in TypeScript so it's probably a little more strict.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma if that is just a warning so maybe your linting rules are strict, you could think of ignore lint check for that line