# Javascript ternary operator where a result can be a string and function

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

All,

What I would like to achieve is something resembling the below, but I'm unsure if it's possible. If the value is equal to the files length, I would like to update the string to `done` but also call a function on complete. I'm thinking that this isn't the best place to put the function call, but curious to know if it's possible and if it's good practise.

```
   {{ value == files.length ? 'Done'; resetFileInput() : 'Pending' }}
```

Comment: Seeing that you have curly brackets, I assume this is done in-template? Chances are, you might better off using a computed or the likes of it, depending on the framework/library you are using.

Comment: Why not just use an `if` - you're misusing ternary operators trying to do this

Comment: Thanks Terry - That's correct, it's inside a template.

Comment: If you can call a function, you can just make a function that returns the correct string and also calls whatever you want, then do `{{ myFunction(value, files) }}` or pass whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec - My question was essentially asking if it's essentially misusing it / if it's possible. Based on your response, i'm assuming it's not! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I execute multiple functions on the result of a ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950027/how-to-i-execute-multiple-functions-on-the-result-of-a-ternary-operation) The top answer says its not good practice

Comment: @VLAZ - That works a treat thanks. Feel free to add an answer. `{{value == files.length? : resetFileInput() : 'Pending' }}' with the function returning the string as well as emptying the input

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making harder to read and maintain code, you should extract the logic into a new function:

```js
function myFunction(value, files) {
    if (value == files.length) {
        resetFileInput();
        return 'Done';
    }
    return 'Pending';
}
```

which you then call from your template:

```
{{ myFunction(value, files) }}
```

That way you do not put too much logic in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can have have as many values as you want in a comma seperated list (with `(` and `)`). All functions will be ran and the last of the list will be 'returned'.

`true`:

```js
console.log(true ? (alert("hi"), 'Done') : 'Pending')
```

`false`:

```js
console.log(false ? (alert("hi"), 'Done') : 'Pending')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```js
const resetFileInput = () => {
    console.log("Reset file input")
}
 
const done = () => {
  resetFileInput()
  return "done"
}

let files = ["file"]
let value = files.length ? done() : "Pending"

console.log(value)
```